# Spring JDBC templet using annotation is comming as null

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

I am new to spring DAO and spring JDBC templet and i am getting null at JDBC templet in the below code and i have checked some examples and everything looks fine in my code. Please let me know if i missed something

Class code:

```
import com.bnym.repo.rule.Deal;
import com.bnym.repo.rule.Security;
@Repository
public class Test {
                @Resource(name = "jdbcTemplate")
                private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
                @Resource(name = "namedParameterJdbcTemplate")
                private NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;           

                Deal deal= new Deal();
                public static void main(String[] args) {

                                Security sec1 = new Security();
                                Set<String> sec1Index = new HashSet<String>();
                                sec1Index.add("NP");
                                sec1.setSecurityCategory("Fixed Income");
                                sec1.setBroadType("sdsdfs");
                                sec1.setCountry("fsdf");
                                sec1.setCurrency("AUD");
                                sec1.setIndex(sec1Index);
                                sec1.setIssuerGroup("AAAAA");
                                sec1.setIssuerName("issuerName");
                                sec1.setIssuerRating(10);
                                sec1.setIssueSize(111111);
                                sec1.setMarketCap(11111);
                                sec1.setMonthsToMaturity(10);
                                sec1.setRepoSecurityID("111");
                                sec1.setRepoSecurityIdType("repoSecurityIdType");
                                sec1.setSecurityPrice(22222222);
                                sec1.setSecurityRating(88);
                                sec1.setSecuritySubType("Stripped Government Bond");
                                sec1.setTaxDocReceived(true);
                                sec1.setUnratedSecurities(false);

                                Security sec2 = new Security();
                                sec2.setSecurityCategory("dasdas");
                                sec2.setBroadType("Bond");
                                sec2.setCountry("Japan");
                                sec2.setCurrency("AUD");
                                Set<String> sec2Index = new HashSet<String>();
                                sec2Index.add("NP");
                                sec2.setIndex(sec2Index);
                                sec2.setIssuerGroup("AAAAA");
                                sec2.setIssuerName("issuerName");
                                sec2.setIssuerRating(10);
                                sec2.setIssueSize(111111);
                                sec2.setMarketCap(11111);
                                sec2.setMonthsToMaturity(10);
                                sec2.setRepoSecurityID("222");
                                sec2.setRepoSecurityIdType("repoSecurityIdType");
                                sec2.setSecurityPrice(22222222);
                                sec2.setSecurityRating(10);
                                sec2.setSecuritySubType("Stripped Government Bond");
                                sec2.setTaxDocReceived(true);
                                sec2.setUnratedSecurities(false);

                                Security sec3 = new Security();
                                sec3.setSecurityCategory("dasdas");
                                sec3.setBroadType("Bond");
                                sec3.setCountry("Italy");
                                sec3.setCurrency("sdfsd");
                                Set<String> sec3Index = new HashSet<String>();
                                sec3Index.add("NP");
                                sec3.setIndex(sec3Index);                         
                                sec3.setIssuerGroup("AAAAA");
                                sec3.setIssuerName("issuerName");
                                sec3.setIssuerRating(10);
                                sec3.setIssueSize(111111);
                                sec3.setMarketCap(11111);
                                sec3.setMonthsToMaturity(10);
                                sec3.setRepoSecurityID("333");
                                sec3.setRepoSecurityIdType("repoSecurityIdType");
                                sec3.setSecurityPrice(22222222);
                                sec3.setSecurityRating(10);
                                sec3.setSecuritySubType("Stripped Government Bond");
                                sec3.setTaxDocReceived(true);
                                sec3.setUnratedSecurities(false);

                                Security sec4 = new Security();
                                sec4.setSecurityCategory("dasdas");
                                sec4.setBroadType("EQTY");
                                sec4.setCountry("Portugal");
                                sec4.setCurrency("sdfsd");
                                Set<String> sec4Index = new HashSet<String>();
                                sec4Index.add("NP");
                                sec4.setIndex(sec4Index);
                                sec4.setIssuerGroup("AAAAA");
                                sec4.setIssuerName("issuerName");
                                sec4.setIssuerRating(10);
                                sec4.setIssueSize(111111);
                                sec4.setMarketCap(11111);
                                sec4.setMonthsToMaturity(10);
                                sec4.setRepoSecurityID("444");
                                sec4.setRepoSecurityIdType("repoSecurityIdType");
                                sec4.setSecurityPrice(22222222);
                                sec4.setSecurityRating(10);
                                sec4.setSecuritySubType("Common Stock");
                                sec4.setTaxDocReceived(false);
                                sec4.setUnratedSecurities(false);

                                Security sec5 = new Security();
                                sec5.setSecurityCategory("Fixed Income");
                                sec5.setBroadType("sdsdfs");
                                sec5.setCountry("fsdf");
                                sec5.setCurrency("AUD");
                                Set<String> sec5Index = new HashSet<String>();
                                sec5Index.add("NP");
                                sec5.setIndex(sec5Index);
                                sec5.setIssuerGroup("Dexia SA");
                                sec5.setIssuerName("issuerName");
                                sec5.setIssuerRating(10);
                                sec5.setIssueSize(111111);
                                sec5.setMarketCap(11111);
                                sec5.setMonthsToMaturity(10);
                                sec5.setRepoSecurityID("555");
                                sec5.setRepoSecurityIdType("repoSecurityIdType");
                                sec5.setSecurityPrice(22222222);
                                sec5.setSecurityRating(88);
                                sec5.setSecuritySubType("Stripped Government Bond");
                                sec5.setTaxDocReceived(true);
                                sec5.setUnratedSecurities(false);

                                Security sec6 = new Security();
                                sec6.setSecurityCategory("dasdas");
                                sec6.setBroadType("Bond");
                                sec6.setCountry("dsds");
                                sec6.setCurrency("sdfsd");
                                Set<String> sec6Index = new HashSet<String>();
                                sec6Index.add("NP");
                                sec6.setIndex(sec6Index);
                                sec6.setIssuerGroup("AAAAA");
                                sec6.setIssuerName("issuerName");
                                sec6.setIssuerRating(10);
                                sec6.setIssueSize(111111);
                                sec6.setMarketCap(11111);
                                sec6.setMonthsToMaturity(10);
                                sec6.setRepoSecurityID("666");
                                sec6.setRepoSecurityIdType("repoSecurityIdType");
                                sec6.setSecurityPrice(22222222);
                                sec6.setSecurityRating(10);
                                sec6.setSecuritySubType("Supranational Bond");
                                sec6.setTaxDocReceived(true);
                                sec6.setUnratedSecurities(false);

                                Security sec7 = new Security();
                                sec7.setSecurityCategory("Equities");
                                sec7.setBroadType("EQTY");
                                sec7.setCountry("Australia");
                                sec7.setCurrency("AUD");
                                Set<String> sec7Index = new HashSet<String>();
                                sec7Index.add("S&P/ASX20");
                                sec7.setIndex(sec7Index);
                                sec7.setIssuerGroup("AAAAA");
                                sec7.setIssuerName("issuerName");
                                sec7.setIssuerRating(10);
                                sec7.setIssueSize(111111);
                                sec7.setMarketCap(11111);
                                sec7.setMonthsToMaturity(10);
                                sec7.setRepoSecurityID("777");
                                sec7.setRepoSecurityIdType("repoSecurityIdType");
                                sec7.setSecurityPrice(22222222);
                                sec7.setSecurityRating(10);
                                sec7.setSecuritySubType("Common Stock");
                                sec7.setTaxDocReceived(true);
                                sec7.setUnratedSecurities(false);

                                Security sec8 = new Security();
                                sec8.setSecurityCategory("Equities");
                                sec8.setBroadType("EQTY");
                                sec8.setCountry("Australia");
                                sec8.setCurrency("AUD");
                                Set<String> sec8Index = new HashSet<String>();
                                sec8Index.add("S&P/ASX20");
                                sec8.setIndex(sec8Index);
                                sec8.setIssuerGroup("AAAAA");
                                sec8.setIssuerName("issuerName");
                                sec8.setIssuerRating(10);
                                sec8.setIssueSize(111111);
                                sec8.setMarketCap(11111);
                                sec8.setMonthsToMaturity(10);
                                sec8.setRepoSecurityID("888");
                                sec8.setRepoSecurityIdType("repoSecurityIdType");
                                sec8.setSecurityPrice(22222222);
                                sec8.setSecurityRating(10);
                                sec8.setSecuritySubType("Common Stock");
                                sec8.setTaxDocReceived(true);
                                sec8.setUnratedSecurities(false);
                                List<Security> securities= new ArrayList<Security>();

                                securities.add(sec1);
                                securities.add(sec2);
                                securities.add(sec3);
                                securities.add(sec4);
                                securities.add(sec5);
                                securities.add(sec6);
                                securities.add(sec7);
                                securities.add(sec8);
                                Deal deal = new Deal();
                                Test t =new Test();
                                t.checkTaxRule(securities);


                }             



                                public List<Security> checkTaxRule(List<Security> securities){
                                int count= 0;
                                String reason="fail due to tax rule";
                                List<Security> passsecurities = null;
                                MapSqlParameterSource params = new MapSqlParameterSource();
                                List<Map<String,Object>> rows = null;
                                params.addValue("userId", "3h9author1");
                                final String query="SELECT * FROM T_ECT_USER WHERE USER_ID=:userId ";

                                rows = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.queryForList(query, params);
                                for(Security security: securities){
                                                for(Map<String,Object> rule :rows){
                                                                if(security.getCountry()==rule.get("COUNTRY_CODE") && security.getSecuritySubType()==rule.get("SECURITY_SUBTYPE")){
                                                                                deal.addEligibleSecurity(security, reason);
                                                                                break;
                                                                }
                                                                else{
                                                                                count++;
                                                                }
                                                                if(count==rows.size()){
                                                                                deal.addNonEligibleSecurity(security, reason);
                                                                }

                                                }


                                }


                                return  null;

                }
}
```

I am running this as a java application (Run as java application)

Below is the configuration file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:ctx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd ttp://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
       <!-- property files -->
       <ctx:property-placeholder location="classpath*:*.properties" />
       <!-- database access -->
       <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
              <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}" />
              <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
              <property name="username" value="${db.user}" />
              <property name="password" value="${db.password}" />
       </bean>
       <bean id="pool" class="org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool">
              <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis">
                     <value>300000</value>
              </property>
              <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis">
                     <value>60000</value>
              </property>
       </bean>
       <bean id="dsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.DataSourceConnectionFactory">
              <constructor-arg>
                     <ref bean="dataSource" />
              </constructor-arg>
       </bean>
       <bean id="poolableConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory">
              <constructor-arg index="0">
                     <ref bean="dsConnectionFactory" />
              </constructor-arg>
              <constructor-arg index="1">
                     <ref bean="pool" />
              </constructor-arg>
              <constructor-arg index="2">
                     <null />
              </constructor-arg>
              <constructor-arg index="3">
                     <null />
              </constructor-arg>
              <!-- read only -->
              <constructor-arg index="4">
                     <value>false</value>
              </constructor-arg>
              <!-- auto commit -->
              <constructor-arg index="5">
                     <value>true</value>
              </constructor-arg>
       </bean>
       <bean id="pooledDS" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource" depends-on="poolableConnectionFactory">
              <constructor-arg>
                     <ref bean="pool" />
              </constructor-arg>
       </bean>
       <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
              <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
       </bean>
       <bean id="namedParameterJdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate">
              <constructor-arg index="0">
                     <ref bean="pooledDS" />
              </constructor-arg>
       </bean>
              <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
              <constructor-arg index="0">
                     <ref bean="pooledDS" />
              </constructor-arg>
       </bean>

       <bean id="commonDao" class="com.bnym.cm.common.dao.CommonDao" />
       <bean id="idFactory" class="com.bnym.cm.common.impl.IdFactory" />
       <bean id="exceptionHandler" class="com.bnym.cm.common.service.ExceptionHandler" />
       <bean id="messageListener" class="com.bnym.cm.common.jms.CMMessageListener" />
       <bean id="messageSender" class="com.bnym.cm.common.jms.CMMessageSender" />

       <bean id="mqConnectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory">
              <property name="hostName" value="${jms.hostname.local}" />
              <property name="port" value="${jms.port.local}" />
              <property name="queueManager" value="${jms.queue.manager.local}" />
       </bean>

       <bean id="jmsQueueConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory">
              <property name="targetConnectionFactory" ref="mqConnectionFactory" />
       </bean>

       <bean id="jmsDestinationResolver" class="org.springframework.jms.support.destination.DynamicDestinationResolver" />

       <bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
              <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsQueueConnectionFactory" />
              <property name="destinationResolver" ref="jmsDestinationResolver" />
              <property name="defaultDestinationName" value="${jms.queue.rep.local}" />
              <property name="pubSubDomain" value="false" />
              <property name="receiveTimeout" value="20000" />
       </bean>

       <bean id="jmsContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
           <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsQueueConnectionFactory"/>
           <property name="destinationName" value="${jms.queue.esb.local}"/>
           <property name="messageListener" ref="messageListener" />
       </bean>

       <beans profile="Dev">
              <bean id="mqConnectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory">
                     <property name="hostName" value="${jms.hostname.Dev}" />
                     <property name="port" value="${jms.port.Dev}" />
                     <property name="queueManager" value="${jms.queue.manager.Dev}" />
                  <property name="transportType" value="${jms.transport.type.Dev}" />
                     <property name="channel" value="${jms.client.channel.Dev}" /> 
              </bean>      

              <bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
                     <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsQueueConnectionFactory" />
                     <property name="destinationResolver" ref="jmsDestinationResolver" />
                     <property name="defaultDestinationName" value="${jms.queue.rep.Dev}" />
                     <property name="pubSubDomain" value="false" />
                     <property name="receiveTimeout" value="20000" />
              </bean>      

              <bean id="jmsContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
                  <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsQueueConnectionFactory"/>
                  <property name="destinationName" value="${jms.queue.esb.Dev}"/>
                  <property name="messageListener" ref="messageListener" />
              </bean>
       </beans>

       <beans profile="QA">
              <bean id="mqConnectionFactory" class="com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory">
                     <property name="hostName" value="${jms.hostname.QA}" />
                     <property name="port" value="${jms.port.QA}" />
                     <property name="queueManager" value="${jms.queue.manager.QA}" />
                  <property name="transportType" value="${jms.transport.type.QA}" />
                     <property name="channel" value="${jms.client.channel.QA}" /> 
              </bean>      

              <bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
                     <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsQueueConnectionFactory" />
                     <property name="destinationResolver" ref="jmsDestinationResolver" />
                     <property name="defaultDestinationName" value="${jms.queue.rep.QA}" />
                     <property name="pubSubDomain" value="false" />
                     <property name="receiveTimeout" value="20000" />
              </bean>      

              <bean id="jmsContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
                  <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsQueueConnectionFactory"/>
                  <property name="destinationName" value="${jms.queue.esb.QA}"/>
                  <property name="messageListener" ref="messageListener" />
              </bean>
       </beans>     
</beans>
```

namedParameterJdbcTemplate is comming as null

Answer (score 2):

Your main method never creates any Spring context, and doesn't get the Test bean from a Spring context. So there's no way Spring can magically know that you have created a Test instance and inject JDBC templates inside.

If you're getting a Spring bean using

```
new Test()
```

as you're doing, it's not a Spring bean. It's just a regular Java object that Spring is not aware of.

Read [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans)

Comment: got it yar. so i have to initialize ApplicationContext and then create a object for the test class to make it work right ?

Comment: You have to create a context, and ask this context for the bean of class Test.

Comment: i am a bit new to spring so what i should do is  1. add the test in the configaration file or add @resource annotation and give a name. 2. Give that name in the getBean  right ?. context.getBean('test calss Id');

Comment: `context.getBean(Test.class)`.

Comment: Sorry i have edited my response above.adding the spring Class in the configaration file or putting @resource annotation is a must right ?. Apologies asking asking all these basic questions as i am new to spring

Comment: Take the time to learn properly: read that documentation. And go steap by step: why do you have dozens of beans (jms, etc.) in your xml file since you're not using them, and haven't even tried loading it yet wth just the beans you need?